# Set common y axis limits from a list of ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running a function that returns a custom ggplot from an input data (it is in fact a plot with several layers on it). I run the function over several different input data and obtain a list of ggplots.

I want to create a grid with these plots to compare them but they all have different y axes.

I guess what I have to do is extract the maximum and minimum y axes limits from the ggplot list and apply those to each plot in the list.

How can I do that? I guess its through the use of ggbuild. Something like this:

```
test = ggplot_build(plot_list[[1]])

> test$layout$panel_scales_x
[[1]]
<ScaleContinuousPosition>
 Range:  
 Limits:    0 --    1
```

I am not familiar with the structure of a ggplot_build and maybe this one in particular is not a standard one as it comes from a "custom" ggplot.

For reference, these plots are created whit the `gseaplot2` function from the `enrichplot` package.

I dont know how to "upload" an R object but if that would help, let me know how to do it.

Thanks!

**edit after comments (thanks for your suggestions!)**

Here is an example of the a `gseaplot2` plot. GSEA stands for Gene Set Enrichment Analysis, it is a technique used in genomic studies. The `gseaplot2` function calculates a running average and then plots it and another bar plot on the bottom.

[image]

and here is the grid I create to compare the plots generated from different data:

[image]

I would like to have a common scale for the "Running Enrichment Score" part.

I guess I could try to recreate the gseaplot2 function and input all of the datasets and then create the grid by facet_wrap, but I was wondering if there was an easy way of extracting parameters from a plot list.

As a reproducible example (from the enrichplot package):

```
library(clusterProfiler)

data(geneList, package="DOSE")
gene <- names(geneList)[abs(geneList) > 2]
wpgmtfile <- system.file("extdata/wikipathways-20180810-gmt-Homo_sapiens.gmt", package="clusterProfiler")
wp2gene <- read.gmt(wpgmtfile)
wp2gene <- wp2gene %>% tidyr::separate(term, c("name","version","wpid","org"), "%")
wpid2gene <- wp2gene %>% dplyr::select(wpid, gene) #TERM2GENE
wpid2name <- wp2gene %>% dplyr::select(wpid, name) #TERM2NAME
ewp2 <- GSEA(geneList, TERM2GENE = wpid2gene, TERM2NAME = wpid2name, verbose=FALSE)

gseaplot2(ewp2, geneSetID=1, subplots=1:2)
```

[image]

And this is how I generate the plot list (probably there is a much more elegant way):

```
plot_list = list()
for(i in 1:3) {
  fig_i = gseaplot2(ewp2, 
            geneSetID=i,
            subplots=1:2)
  plot_list[[i]] = fig_i
}
ggarrange(plotlist=plot_list)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you use `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`?

Comment: Ways which describe how to post a good question can be found on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and on [R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/three-tips-for-posting-good-questions-to-r-help-and-stack-overflow/).  What is always appreciated by people willing to help is a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You are referencing to plots created with `gseaplot2`,  but no plot can be seen.

Comment: Agree with @alistaire.  Using `facet_wrap` can allow for many different plots to be added and just be sure to set `scales="free_x"` if you can.  If your plots have the same x axis and y axis aesthetics, this is probably the way to go.  You'll have to add an ID column, mash the dataframes together, then facet on that ID column.  Should work.

Comment: +1 for the previous suggestions.  If there are too many plots for `facet_XXXX` to be an option (though see [`facet_grid_paginate`](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggforce/man/facet_grid_paginate.html)), then you could manually calculate your axis limits in advance and then use `coord_cartesian` to set a common range on all the axes.  [NB using `xlim=` or `ylim=` in a `scale_XXXX` function *clips* the data, which may have unwelcome side effects.]

Comment: @chemdork123 I have added some examples. The issue is that the gseaplot2 function does come calculations before returning the plot. Is there any way of extracting the data from the plot list? Once I have the data merged I could figure a way of adding the ID and then plotting with facet_wrap.